# Providing IConfiguration parameter in Activator.CreateInstance (reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

I have this code which is using reflection to create instance of HL7MessageGenerator:

```
public static List<IHL7MessageGenerator> ReadAssemblies(IOptions<AppSettings> a_mConfig)
        {
            var pluginsLists = new List<IHL7MessageGenerator>();
            try
            {
                //Read the dll files from the folder
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(a_mConfig.Value.PluginFilesPath, a_mConfig.Value.PluginFilesFormat);

                if (files == null)
                    throw new OHException(ExceptionMessage.FILE_NOT_FOUND);

                //Read the assembly from files
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var d = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), file);
                    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), file));

                    //Exteract all the types that implements IPlugin 
                    var pluginTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IHL7MessageGenerator).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface).ToArray();

                    foreach (var pluginType in pluginTypes)
                    {
                        //Create an instance from the extracted type 
                        var pluginInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType) as IHL7MessageGenerator;
                        pluginsLists.Add(pluginInstance);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new OHException($"{ExceptionMessage.UNABLE_TO_READ_DLL} because : {ex.Message}");
            }
            return pluginsLists;
        }
```

I have these two constructors in my HL7MessageGenerator class:

```
public HL7MessageGenerator()
        {

        }
        public HL7MessageGenerator(IConfiguration a_mconfig)
        {
            m_config = a_mconfig;
            m_awsKeyId = m_config.GetSection("awsConfig").GetSection("awsKeyId").Value;
            m_awsKeySecret = m_config.GetSection("awsConfig").GetSection("awsKeySecret").Value;
            m_region = m_config.GetSection("awsConfig").GetSection("region").Value;
            m_destinationNumber = m_config.GetSection("awsConfig").GetSection("destinationNumber").Value;
            m_message = "";
            m_messageType = m_config.GetSection("awsConfig").GetSection("messageType").Value;
            m_appId = m_config.GetSection("awsConfig").GetSection("appId").Value;

            m_BlobSasUrl = m_config.GetSection("AppSettings").GetSection("BlobSasUrl").Value;
            m_BlobContainer = m_config.GetSection("AppSettings").GetSection("BlobSasUrl").Value;
        }
```

I am trying to call parameterized constructor in HL7MessageGenerator class.
from examles I can see that this is how you do it:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param)
```

This is what I am trying:

```
var pluginInstance=Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType , a_mConfig) as IHL7MessageGenerator;
```

But I am getting an error:
`Constructor on type 'ONQHL7MessageGenerator_V1.HL7MessageGenerator' not found.`

Comment: The typed constructor expects an object of type `Configuration` but you are passing `Options<AppSettings>` those are not the same.

Comment: @Eldar , thanks for the help. I corrected it and it now works.